# Кастомный выпадающий список стран при помощи API

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать кастомный список стран используя API.
Вот fetch код:

```
// country list generate
const countryList = document.querySelector('.form-list.country');

fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res => {
  return res.json();
}).then(data => {
  let output = '';
  data.forEach(country => {
    output += `<li class="form-item" data-value="${country.name.common}">${country.name.common}</li>`;
    countryList.innerHTML = output;
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

[полный код html, css, js](https://codepen.io/KaterynaKravchuk/pen/RwQKyma)
Во втором списке "Country" список формируется, но название страны не поставляется в форму, а атрибут "data-value="" " в инпут ниже. В первом списке "Guests Amount" все ок, т.к. данные прописаны в html. Нужен такой же со странами.

Сразу скажу, с тегом select все работает, но мне нужна стилизованная выпадашка. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема заключается в том, что

```
const openItems = openList.querySelectorAll('.form-item');
```

Находит два списка, НО так как второй список (страны) через fetch, то он просто еще не успевает загрузится и от рисоваться в DOM. querySelectorAll срабатывает быстрее, поэтому во втором списке ничего нет

Данную задачу можно сделать так, немного переделал логику

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.select-btn').forEach(function (selectWrapper) {
    selectWrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e){

      const openList = selectWrapper.nextElementSibling;
      const hiddenInput = openList.nextElementSibling;
      const openItems = openList.querySelectorAll('.form-item'); 

      openList.classList.toggle('open');

      if (e.target != selectWrapper) {
        openList.classList.remove('open');
      }

      openItems.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click',function(){
          selectWrapper.innerText = this.innerText;
          openList.classList.remove('open');
          hiddenInput.value = this.dataset.value;
        }) 
      })
    })

})

// country list generate
const countryList = document.querySelector('.form-list.country');

fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res => {
  return res.json();
}).then(data => {
  let output = '';
  data.forEach(country => {
    output += `<li class="form-item" data-value="${country.name.common}">${country.name.common}</li>`;
    countryList.innerHTML = output;
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

```css
      .form {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        width: 500px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 50px 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
}
.form-select {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-list {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 45px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #ccc;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 8px;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        z-index: 2;
}
.form-list.open {
        display: block;
}
.form-list.country {
        height: 400px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
}
.form-item {
        padding: 6px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #ccc;
        transition: all .2s;
}
.form-item:hover {
        background-color: #f3f0f0;
}
.form-item:last-child {
        border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-item:first-child {
        padding-top: 10px;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
.hidden-input {
/*         display: none; */
}
.select-btn {
        display: inline;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 6px 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        color: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.select-btn:focus {
        outline: none;
        border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-select">
      <button class="select-btn" type="button">Guests Amount</button>
      <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="form-item" data-value="onePerson">1 Guest</li>
        <li class="form-item" data-value="twoPerson">2 Guests</li>
        <li class="form-item" data-value="threePerson">3 Guests</li>
        <li class="form-item" data-value="fourPerson">4 Guests</li>
        <li class="form-item" data-value="fivePerson">5 Guests</li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" class="hidden-input">
   </div>
    <div class="form-select">
      <button class="select-btn" type="button">Country</button>
      <ul class="form-list country"></ul>
      <input type="text" class="hidden-input">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде понимала, что проблема с отрисовкой в DOM, но как решить не знала. Чуть раньше на хабре предложили заменить индивидуальный обработчик клика на делегированный:
`openList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const item = e.target.closest('li.form-item');
  if (item) {
    openBtn.innerText = item.innerText;
    openList.classList.remove('open');
    hiddenInput.value = item.dataset.value;
  }
});`
Ваш вариант тоже обмозгую, чтоб в копилку знаний прибывало.

Comment: Пожалуйста, если помог отметьте галочкой мой ответ ))